# Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function MYSQL ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1111

I´m trying to find a list of students who are below the average grade of course

I have this query

```
Select studentName 
from courseGrade 
where grade < avg(grade) and sectionID=290001
```

Comment: Hint:  You need a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to compute the average grade of the course. For example:

```
select studentName 
from courseGrade 
where sectionID = 290001
  and grade < (
    select avg(grade) from courseGrade where sectionID = 290001
  )
```